# Activating graphic creation from button using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I need to have 2 graphic layers. One is used to set a starting location on a network, and the other is used to mark a stopping location.

There should only be a maximum of 1 feature in each layer. So, a single starting point, and a single stopping point.

I'd like the user to be able to click a button called, for example, `Set Starting Location` which would activate that graphic layer and allow the user to put a point on the map. Then there'd be another button that they could click called, for example, `Set Stopping Location` which would work the same way.

How do I make it so one button activates one graphic layer, and another button actives the other graphic layer? I'd also want to allow only 1 feature per layer, which I assume I'd use some type of count function.

The geometry of these graphics would eventually be used in a Python geoprocessing tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample defining your request :

The code bellow or either see [Live FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/xosmvhL8/)

**HTML** :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var dojoConfig = {
    async: true
};
</script>
<body class="claro">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" design="headline" splitters="false" id="DashboardContainer">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="DashboardTop" region="top">
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="setStart" type="button">
          Set Starting Location
        </button>
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="setStop" type="button">
          Set Stopping Location
        </button>
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="clear" type="button">
          clear !
        </button>
        |
        <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="send" type="button">
          Send request
        </button>
      </div>
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" region="center" id="map" >
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**JS :**

```
require(['esri/map',"esri/toolbars/draw", "dojo/on",'dojo/parser','dojo/ready','dijit/registry',"esri/layers/GraphicsLayer","esri/graphic","esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol",'dijit/layout/BorderContainer','dijit/layout/ContentPane',],
function (Map,Draw,On,parser,ready,registry,GraphicsLayer,Graphic,PictureMarkerSymbol,BorderContainer,ContentPane) {
  //parser.parse();
  var urlIcoStart ="http://www.mymanatee.org/arcgis_js_api/library/3.12/arcgis/esri/dijit/images/Directions/maneuvers/esriDMTStopOrigin.png";
  var urlIcoStop ="http://www.mymanatee.org/arcgis_js_api/library/3.12/arcgis/esri/dijit/images/Directions/maneuvers/esriDMTStopDestination.png"
  var map;
  var toolbar;
  var startGrpahicLayer = new GraphicsLayer({id:"startLyr"});
  var stopGrpahicLayer = new GraphicsLayer({id:"stopLyr"});;
  var symbolstart = new PictureMarkerSymbol(urlIcoStart, 15, 20);
  var symbolstop = new PictureMarkerSymbol(urlIcoStop, 15, 20);

  var clickedBtn ="";

  ready(function(){


    map = new Map("map", {
        basemap: "streets",
        center: [-90, 39],
        zoom: 9
    });

    map.on("load",function(){
      toolbar = new Draw(map);
      toolbar.on("draw-end", addToMap);
      map.addLayers([startGrpahicLayer,stopGrpahicLayer]);
    });

    On(registry.byId("setStart"),"click",function(e){
      if(startGrpahicLayer.graphics.length==0){
        toolbar.activate(Draw.POINT);
        map.disableMapNavigation();
        clickedBtn = "start";
      }else{
        alert("Start point already Defined !");
      }
    });

    On(registry.byId("setStop"),"click",function(e){
      if(stopGrpahicLayer.graphics.length==0){
        toolbar.activate(Draw.POINT);
        map.disableMapNavigation();
        clickedBtn = "stop";
      }else{
        alert("Stop point already Defined !");
      }
    });

    On(registry.byId("clear"),"click",function(e){
      startGrpahicLayer.clear();
      stopGrpahicLayer.clear();
    });

    On(registry.byId("send"),"click",function(e){
      yourRequestTogeoprocessingService();
    });

  });


  addToMap = function(evt) {
    var layer ="";
    toolbar.deactivate(); 
    map.enableMapNavigation();
    if(clickedBtn == "start") { symbol = symbolstart; layer = startGrpahicLayer}
    else if(clickedBtn == "stop") {symbol = symbolstop; layer = stopGrpahicLayer}
    else return;
    layer.add(new Graphic(evt.geometry,symbol));
  };



  yourRequestTogeoprocessingService = function(e) {
    if(startGrpahicLayer.graphics.length ==0 || stopGrpahicLayer.graphics.length ==0 ){
      alert("please specify both start and stop locations !!")
      return;
    }

    console.log(startGrpahicLayer.graphics[0]);
    console.log(stopGrpahicLayer.graphics[0]);


    alert("Start point =\n  X : "+startGrpahicLayer.graphics[0].geometry.x+"  |   Y: "+startGrpahicLayer.graphics[0].geometry.y+"\nStop point =\n  X : "+stopGrpahicLayer.graphics[0].geometry.x+"  |   Y: "+stopGrpahicLayer.graphics[0].geometry.y);
  }

});
```

**CSS:**

```
    #DashboardContainer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#DashboardTop {
    height: 30px;
}

html,body{ width: 100%; height: 100%; margin:0px;padding:0px; overflow: hidden;}
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/xosmvhL8/)

Comment: I just saw this. I actually figured it out, and it's very similar to what you did. Thanks a lot for taking the time.

Comment: @geogeogeo you're welcome :)